# store List in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, list, store, global-asax

We can store application level strings in a global.asax file like:
*Global asax:*

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Application.Lock();
        Application["msg"] = "";            
        Application.UnLock();        
    }
```

And then in pages we get the "msg" variable as:
*a.aspx.cs:*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string msg = (string)Application["msg"];
        //manipulating msg..
 }
```

***However, I want to store List of objects as application level variable instead of string msg.*** I tried this:
*Global.asax:*

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Application.Lock();
        List<MyClassName> myobjects= new List<MyClassName>();      
        Application.UnLock();        
    }
```

*a.aspx.cs:*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here I want to get myobjects from the global.asax and manipulate with it..
    }
```

So, *how to store List myobjects as an application level variable in global.asax and work with this?*

Moreover, I have another question:
*How to send any notification to clients(browsers) when global variable in global.asax is changed?*

Comment: What it is a Website or a WebApplication ?

Comment: It is WebSite, otherwise we couldn't add global.asax file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to store it into the cache :

```
using System.Web.Caching;    

protected void Application_Start()
{
   ...
   List<MyClassName> myobjects = new List<MyClassName>();
   HttpContext.Current.Cache["List"] = myobjects;
}
```

then to access / manipulating it :

```
using System.Web.Caching;

var myobjects =  (List<MyClassName>)HttpContext.Cache["List"];
//Changes to myobjects
...
HttpContext.Cache["List"] = myobjects;
```

Comment: last gives compilation errr saying: "for non-static method or field HttpContex.Cache.get" reference to the object is necessary"

Comment: Where do you get this error ? accessing it or setting it in the Application_Start ? See my edit, hope it helps.

Comment: Evertything is OK now, but you forgot word "current" in accessing. It must be var myobjects = (List<MyClassName>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["List"];

Comment: Now, can you answer to my 2nd question? How to send any notification to clients(browsers) when myobjects is changed?

Comment: Isn't it one question per post ? :-)

Comment: I'll try to answer but your question is vague. Well to check if it has changed you can either count the items in it but that wouldn't tell you if the content of one item was changed. To do that you would have to compare it with one original instance that you keep. Do I answer the question ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17928/discussion-between-nurlan-kenzhebekov-and-arno2501)

Comment: In this case clients must access the global variable and compare this with old one periodically, this can be done for example..by the timer. But this is not best way. I thought exists better way to do that..