# Keeping a value between web service calls

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I need to keep a string list between each web service call in the web service side. Simply, this list should not discard after each web service call proceed. It's life time should with web service application start and finish  with web service application stop. something like static variable in the applications.

How to implement such thing in C#.net web-service?

Comment: Just wanna confirm：keep a string list between each web service call——Do you mean when each client sends a request and you should create the string list and send to the client?

Comment: @DWHelper: No, You think I have an IP address list in web service. So, on each web service call, it needs to check if the call comes from one of this IP in the list. So, this IP address list should share between each web service call. I may uses a DB or text file for store this IP list. but in my case I need more efficiency. So, I suppose to store in memory (something sounds like in a global memory)

Comment: Try to implement WCF call back contract, that will take care of client management. Sample project in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29027/Using-WCF-Callback-Services-Throttling

Comment: With services, keeping data in memory can sometimes be less reliable than you would expect, especially when you may not know exactly when the service is spun up/down (e.g. WCF service instances may be created/destroyed as necessary to deal with incoming operation requests, and as such may not share memory between requests). If you need state between requests, its best to put it somewhere reliable, like a DB or file.

Comment: @ToddBowles: But is this case I'm mostly worrying about efficiency. there is no time to write and read from db or text file. because around 100 sessions do the same. so there can be a bottle neck. what do you think about saving in the web application cache?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya I've posted an answer that will probably work, but it would help to know how persistent you need this data to be, and what the data is/will be used for. If you update your original question with that, I can probably give a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

From what you've said, I think you're using an ASP.NET Web Service (please correct me if I am wrong).

You can create a static class that contains a some type of collection (Dictionary, HashSet, whatever) which you can then use to store your information. The upside is that this will be very fast, the downside is that every time the AppDomain for your service is recycled, your data will be purged. **If this is not a problem, then this is probably the simplest option.**

You can stop IIS from recycling your ASP.NET processes, but recycling exists for a reason, and I wouldn't suggest doing this unless you know what the impact will be.

With regards to the actual class, something like this would work:

```
public static class GlobalState
{
    private static HashSet<string> _ipAddresses;
    public static HashSet<string> IPAddresses
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ipAddresses == null) _ipAddresses = new HashSet<string>();
            return _ipAddresses
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use it:

```
*** some code
if (GlobalState.IPAddresses.Contains(ipAddress))
*** some more code
```

Or however you want to leverage the static collection.

**Update:**
I've done some further investigation, and it looks like if you want persistence between AppDomain restarts your choices are limited. Probably either database of some sort or disk.

Also, the solution I gave above, while simple, is poor from a testability point of view, and doesn't take into account concurrency issues that can occur as a result of many multiple calls being made to the service at the same time.

I'd suggest going with something like the following:

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service()
        : this(InMemoryTokensProvider.GetInstance())
    {

    }

    public Service(TokensProvider statePersister)
    {
        _tokens = statePersister;
    }

    private TokensProvider _tokens;

    [WebMethod]
    public string ServiceCall() 
    {
        if (_tokens.Contains("TestToken"))
        {
            return "Token was present!";
        }
        else
        {
            _tokens.Add("TestToken");
            return "Token was added!";
        }
    }
}

public interface TokensProvider
{
    void Add(string token);
    bool Contains(string token);
}

public class InMemoryTokensProvider : TokensProvider
{
    private static InMemoryTokensProvider _instance;
    public static TokensProvider GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null) _instance = new InMemoryTokensProvider();

        return _instance;
    }

    private HashSet<string> _tokens = new HashSet<string>();
    public void Add(string token)
    {
        lock (_tokens)
        {
            _tokens.Add(token);
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(string token)
    {
        lock (_tokens)
        {
            return _tokens.Contains(token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for understanding my issue. In which condition AppDomain recycled? can it be while application ruining? if that it will be a issue of not availability of data. In windows applications. There should be a proper way to store data in application level of asp.net web applications. isn't it?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya IIS won't recycle the AppDomain in a way such that it will make the current request fail, but it could certainly do it between requests at basically any time it feels like resource usage needs to be re-evaluated. It seems like you need something a bit more persistent than what I originally wrote, so I'll go have a look and get back to you. You can probably leverage the Application object, or the ASP.NET Caching architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I think you can define a class-based or static global varible Dictionary：The Key is IP address, while the other string saves your value. You can use ContainsKey or related method to check whether the request IP exists or not and return the value from the dictionary, otherwises please add the new IP address into the dictionary.

Comment: Could you give me some example please?

Comment: how about storing in cache? look at the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857899/store-list-in-global-asax

Comment: Sorry I didn't think you were using an ASP.NET application：If using that, you can save that into the Application instead of Cache, for cache will be overdue after a period of time.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. what do you mean by `save that into the Application`?

Comment: Application["xx"] = dictionary Instance in the Application_Start event.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WCF to create your services, you might want to consider using the SingleInstance mode for your host. It will allow you to keep data between calls. Only one instance will serve all requests, you can use attributes and properties to keep data in memory between calls.

WCF also supports sessions, you can keep the same instance to serve calls from one particular client.

In each case, the throughput will be impacted unless you authorize multithreaded access to your instance(s). Then you have to take care of the concurrency issues.

Another possible and probably better solution would be to use a persistent store to keep the data between multiples calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a singleton class in which you keep your references.